# JProgressBar not visible during reading

Tags: java, swing

I got a java progressbar which loads perfectly, but I can't see the process, only the result. (when the bar finished loading)
I want to see every percentage of the progress. When I run the code, the frame appears but the progressbar doesn't, only when it's on 100%. Where's the problem?

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

       JFrame f = new JFrame("JProgressBar Sample");
       f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       Container content = f.getContentPane();
       progressBar = new JProgressBar();
       progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
       Border border = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Reading...");
       progressBar.setBorder(border);
       content.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
       f.setSize(300, 100);
       f.setVisible(true);

       progressBar.setValue(0);
       inc(); //fill the bar
       //It fills, but I can't se the whole loading...

    }                                        
        //Here's the filling path
    public static void inc(){

        int i=0;
       try{
            while (i<=100){    
            progressBar.setValue(i+10);

            Thread.sleep(1000);
            i+=20;
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            //nothing
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54716324/how-can-i-set-up-my-jprogressbar-to-show-the-progress-of-my-program-loading?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your GUI is not updated while you are running a long process in the GUI's thread, like filling a progress bar and sleeping some seconds.

Just emerge a thread, which will handle the long operation. 
Within this thread set the progress bar to the desired value within a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {...}`.

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        int i=0;
        try{
            while (i<=100){    
                final int tmpI = i+10;
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){ 
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar.setValue(tmpI);
                    }
                });
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                i += 20;
            }
        } catch(Exception ex){
             //nothing
        }
    }
};
Thread t = new Thread(r);
t.start();
```

Comment: yeah, that's exactly what I needed! Thank you @SirFartALot !!